# Duplicate results in mysql query when doing ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[SQL Fiddle if you guys wanna mess around with it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5b278)

I'm unable to reproduce the issue using the fiddle.

Here is the query you can use in the fiddle

```
SELECT n.*, ns.notification_id AS is_read FROM notifications n
LEFT OUTER JOIN notification_status ns
ON n.id = ns.notification_id
LEFT JOIN notification_user_role nur
ON n.id = nur.notification_id
WHERE
(
  n.esb_consultant_id = 19291
  OR
  n.esb_consultant_id = 'role'
)
AND nur.user_role_id = 'pl_sso_regional_vice_president'
AND n.creation_date <= NOW()
AND n.expiration_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I've also placed it lower in this post, but here it's easier to catch the eyes.

---

I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.

I'm working on a notification system. I have 3 tables described below.

I'm trying to get notifications with a `LIMIT` of 10, paginated, 10 per page(so an `OFFSET` of 10). I'm using ajax to load the next 10.

They are to be ordered by priority(from 1 to 6, 1 being displayed first, while 6th being displayed last).

All unread notifications must be displayed first(priority still applies), while read notifications must be displayed last(priority still applies).

Notifications are per role. A user can have several roles(thus the need for another table).

The `notification_status` table described below is used to keep track of which notifications are read.

**Which ever notification is NOT in the `notification_status` table is NOT read**. This is very important. I didn't make this decision. I just have to live with it.

---

To put it into the big picture lets have an example:

Assume we have 14 notifications:

5 of them will be priority 1, unread.

4 of them will be priority > 1, unread.

3 of them will be priority 1, read.

2 of them will be priority > 1, read.

---

The expected display order is the following.

`5 unread priority 1`

`4 unread priority > 1`

`1 read priority 1`

ajax starts here since we have 10 per page

`2 read priority 1`

`2 read priority > 1`

---

The table structure is as follows.

`notifications`

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sticky            | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| priority          | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| esb_consultant_id | varchar(40)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| message_id        | varchar(100)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| esb_params        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     |         |                |
| creation_date     | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| expiration_date   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

`notification_user_role`

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_role_id    | varchar(150)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| notification_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

`notification_status`

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| esb_consultant_id | varchar(20)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| notification_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

---

The query I'm using to retrieve the results:

```
SELECT n.*, ns.notification_id AS is_read FROM notifications n
LEFT OUTER JOIN notification_status ns
ON n.id = ns.notification_id
LEFT JOIN notification_user_role nur
ON n.id = nur.notification_id
WHERE 
(
  n.esb_consultant_id = :consultant_id 
  OR 
  n.esb_consultant_id = :role_all
)
AND nur.user_role_id = :consultant_role
AND n.creation_date <= NOW()
AND n.expiration_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

`$offset` is the page times 10 - so if the page is 0(first page) the offset is 0, if the page is 1(first ajax call) the offset is 10 and so on

`$limit` is the limit, it's always 10.

`:consultant_id` is the user id - unique

`:role_all` is a simple string `all`. It is used for when certain notifications are for all roles(such as a birthday notification). All users have this notification, regardless of role since all of them have a birthday.

---

The problem:

Whenever I'm doing an ajax call I get certain notifications that are duplicated. I'll just post a screenshot of it since it's easier than drawing it.

**Do note that the ajax itself is just part of the way I'm retrieving the results but is not responsible for the duplicates themselvs, I'm absolutely sure. It's not a display issue either, I've double and triple checked that.**

[Before Ajax](https://i.imgur.com/PmpUP49.png)

[After ajax](https://i.imgur.com/ULIrufg.png)

What I've noticed is that if I were to remove this part

`ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC`

from the query. It works fine. No duplicates.

The dump of the query above, with limit removed and order by removed:

[Dump](https://i.imgur.com/ESXUMl9.png)

Sorry for the image but it's easier.

---

I'm using PHP to query the database.

```
  public function all($consultant_id, $consultant_role, $offset = 0) {
    $limit = 10;
    $offset = $offset * 10;

    $query = <<<SQL
SELECT n.*, ns.notification_id AS is_read FROM notifications n
LEFT OUTER JOIN notification_status ns
ON n.id = ns.notification_id
LEFT JOIN notification_user_role nur
ON n.id = nur.notification_id
WHERE 
(
  n.esb_consultant_id = :consultant_id 
  OR 
  n.esb_consultant_id = :role_all
)
AND nur.user_role_id = :consultant_role
AND n.creation_date <= NOW()
AND n.expiration_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC
LIMIT $offset, $limit
SQL;
    $return = $this->connection
      ->query($query
        , [
          ':consultant_role' => $consultant_role,
          ':consultant_id'   => $consultant_id,
          ':role_all'        => NotificationStatus::PL_N_ALL,
        ]
      )->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($return as $item) { // this is added simply for display purposes
      echo $item['id'] . '<br>';
    }

    return $return;
  }
```

The above is a copy+paste of the code used to retrieve the results. The function simply returns the results for displaying, no other magic going around.

The `foreach` is added to simply display the results in the browser.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/BzyyT7m.png) is the image of the output. Notification 10 is duplicated.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/63bYfj7.png) is the exact same code only with 
`ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC` removed. Limit and offset still apply here.

---

I'm not that good at mysql or sql in general and I'm not sure where the problem itself lies.

Any pointing in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Even workarounds or "hacks" I'm fine with.

Comment: "What I've noticed is that if I were to remove this part

ORDER BY n.creation_date DESC, (is_read IS NULL) DESC, n.priority ASC"  thats wierd because ORDER BY doesnt annything to remove duplicates it only simply sorts.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I'm still hoping I've missed something in the code. I'm still checking. It's pretty monolithic so that's a bummer too...

Comment: Did you try running that query via an UI like Workbench or via the command line to see if the result of your query has any duplicates?

Comment: Well SQL LEFT JOIN's can generate duplicated column data or complete row duplicates tho..sure whould love to see example data, the ajax and php code behide this.,,, it might help if you reset the html element $('[id]').html("") (JQuery assumed) before inserting the rows.

Comment: Try to dump the result returned from your query to see if there are any duplicates. If there are none, then your rendering is duplicating the first one maybe.

Comment: How about letting us play with the data a little bit http://sqlfiddle.com :)

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib I'd love to, but it numbers in the thousand of entries and it's a little bit NDA-ish to be honest. For example notification_user_role has 113278 entries.

Comment: it doesn't have to be the whole dump, just the table structure using "SHOW CREATE TABLE" and few rows just enough to recreate your issue, It doesn't even have to be exact data, maybe just some manually created rows, you know it would greatly speed up the debugging process for others. Your call.

Comment: I'll post somee a bit later. When i get a chance to use a proper pc.

Comment: @Andrew Is the dump the result of your query? If so, I don't see duplicates though.

Comment: The duplicates only appear after doing the ajax. I can't explain it either.

Comment: @Andrew Therefore, the problem is not with your query, but the way you render the result.

Comment: I've added a little extra info. Have a look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted at DBA.SE (and has answers there): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198169/duplicate-results-in-mysql-query-when-try-to-sort-by-with-limit-and-offset